# Ensuring Java classes do not import from certain packages

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, checkstyle, findbugs

I have packages like this:

```
com.example.pure
com.example.pure.internal
com.example.other
```

I want to ensure that the classes in the `com.example.pure` package do not have any dependencies on classes in the `com.example.pure.internal` or `com.example.other` packages.

Obviously, I can go through each file manually and eyeball the imports, but I'd like to automate it. I could write some code to do it, but it seems like it might be something that someone else has already solved.

I use Eclipse, so an Eclipse plugin that I could configure to enforce dependency directions would be absolutely ideal, but a command-line utility or Gradle plugin would be great too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Apache Lucene they use [this handy tool called fobidden-apis](https://code.google.com/p/forbidden-apis/) to check that certain apis are not used. It is an Ant task so you can call this easily from inside eclipse

Answer (score 0):

you can compile `com.example.pure` separately alone if it compiles successfully then it's not depends on any other package:

```
-cp path or -classpath path
```

or

```
javac -d bin -cp bin src\...\someclass.java
```

Comment: It does actually depend on other packages that I haven't mentioned, but this is certainly one way I could go. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: You are welcome bro, you can compile it with other package and without **com.example.pure.internal** or **com.example.other** packages to see if it depends on them. anyway I hope the problem will solve.